# PHP Query in what tag is the word.

Tags: php, phpquery

I'm currently using this code to retrieve tags.

```
$title = $pq->find("title")->text();
$h1 = $pq->find("h1")->text();
$p = $pq->find("p")->text();
```

Is this the proper way of doing it?

Secondly I have to see what word from my array `$array_words` is in which tag. So i have retrieved the `file_get_contents` and removed all tags and put all words in an array. Now lets take this for example:

```
Array
(
    [0] => hello
    [1] => there
    [2] => this
    [3] => is
    [4] => a
    [8] => test
    [9] => array
)
```

and this would be the HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            hello there
        </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>
           this is a
        </h1>
        <p>
           test array
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

How can I find out which word is found in which tag?

I hope I made somewhat clear what I'm trying to do.

Comment: What library are you using , or witch class are you instanciating in $pq variable?

Comment: @MauricioPiberFão `$pq = phpQuery::newDocument($file);` this is how i set `$pq` if that is what you mean =/ Library isn't that just php 5? I'm new to phpquery so forgive my ignorance

Answer (score 0):

Based on the question, the point is that you need to create a reference of which word from $array_words is in some HTML tag.

So you have a array of tags that you want to check, right?

What i'm seen is it:

1. Get All Tags That you Want to Check.
2. Put All Tags on a Foreach to check all.
3. On Foreach, use phpQuery to find the words inside those tags.
4. phpQuery should return text, so you should break in into a new array of words called "$words_from_text", using explode. A new array are created.
5. Use a "in_array" comparator into a new foreach (inside the old one) to find what words from $array_words are inside the text.
6. If a Key From $words_from_text is find in the $array_words, put in on the array of Tags by setting a new array attached to the tag key.

   $array_tags = (
       'h1','div','title',
   )

   $array_words = 
   (
       [0] => hello 
       [1] => there
       [2] => this
       [3] => is
       [4] => a
       [8] => test
       [9] => array
   )

Final Array with the results should be like it :

```
$array_tags = array(
   ['title'] = array('word1','word2'),
   ['h1']    = array('word3','word4'),
   ['div']   = array('word5','word6')
);
```

So if this example is what you need, you can use this guideline to resolve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your help! But i decided to do it like this: First i set the `$title` like i did in the question. Then in my foreach loop for my `$array_words` i just added an `if` like this: `if (strpos($title, $key) !== false)`